# How to combine multiple animated GIFs into one GIF grid

Tags: java, php, android, gif, animated-gif

As part of a project, we need to programmatically combine multiple animated GIFs into one main animated GIF (one gif file), in the form of a grid.

We don't care if it is done on the client-side (i.e. a smartphone with ios/android), or on the server-side (i.e. php with Imagemagick). In either case, we **do not want** a gridview of separate gif files.

Is there any solution or suggestion on how this can be achieved?

### Example:

Let's assume that we have a 4x4 grid (16 cells), with a different individual animated GIF image being shown in each cell; in such a way that each image is animating on its own. Therefore, creating a gif of 16 different videos/animations, all playing at the same time in 16 separate cells.

Comment: Use http://picasion.com/ ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch we need to perform this programmatically, and maybe this would be a good example of what I mean: http://youtu.be/ZKpFFD7aX3c?t=48s (spoiler alert if you haven't seen the matrix)

Comment: Please update your question with the php (or other) code you've tried so far.

Comment: I believe you haven't understood what I mean. so please don't downvote the question if you don't understand it.

The problem is, how do you merge multiple animated images together in the same frame (say a 4x4 grid of gif images, all displaying different things at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I believe that you'll need create 4-up representation of your images.

1. Create a canvas (or similar - depending on implementation language) to become the frame,
2. Every frame of your source(s) must then be spliced (or drawn) into one of a) top-left, b) top-right, c) bottom-left, d) bottom-right,
3. Save each frame to a new image (at 4 times the resolution and composed as in step (2),
4. Combine those frames created in step (3) into a new image as in any animated format.

Or use html to create a web page and render the 4 images as in Step (2) above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is the solution that I had in mind myself, but I have considered it as a last resort. Especially since the frame rate of the gifs may differ, and requiring lots of computing resources. If I want to start skipping frames, I may also lose focused frames. I am mainly looking to see if there might be an easier solution/library to achieve this.

Comment: GIFs don't really have a high frame rate; and you could reset that on your input files. There is software (e.g. ImageMagick) to extract each frame. But you'll have to re-assemble them into your movie. Or buy some commercial video editing software.